# Who would partake in a Topic of the yet-to-be-finalised-period chat discussion?

Tags: chat-event, discussion, community

I'm thinking of holding a regular chat session to discus the `Topic of the X` thread we are intending to run. This would be a good way to address what people want to do with and get out of such a thing, and it would let people raise their voice on subject, in a much better way than trying to poll via answers here.

So would you take part?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you please add more details, like an example, indication of the format, time required, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Let's bump this… I would, if it's at a convenient time for me (roughly 19–00 UTC, also earlier on week-ends).

However I'm not 100% convinced that we *should* keep up a topic of the time period regularly. This risks driving “artificial” questions, made up under constraint. It would be better for highlighted topics to be related to some event (pity we missed the Hugos — is it too late to have a Hugo winners event?).

Comment: The premiere of the final season of Fringe is next week.  May that be the type of reason you're looking for?

Comment: Most of the topics of the week were tied to some event.

Comment: @Izkata Yes, exactly. Some external reason for many people to care about the topic. The first week of a new series sounds like the right time, when people will be (re)watching previous seasons, will have forgotten or not have seen what happened before, etc.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I don't want artificial questions. That's why one idea is to spend the fortnight after/during(?) simply rewarding good answers in the topic field, whether or not they are on new questions. Also part of the discussion should be 'Do we need a topic this week?'